# Error initializing a vector with local objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I want to create a vector with diferent object of type A but ...

This code throws this exception:
     free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000401757 ***

```
#include <vector>

class A
{
    char * elem;

public:
    A()
    {
        elem = new char[10];
    }
    void setA(char* name)
    {
        elem = name;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        delete[] elem;
    }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<A> v_a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        A m_a;
        m_a.setA("jaja");
        v_a.push_back(m_a);

    }
}
```

Why this is happening?? How can implement a correct solution?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to find the point in your program where it fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `setA(...)` you are not copying the *data* of the string, instead you are copying the *address* of a local string. (Check what [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/#stringliterals) says about pointers and string literals)

After the block with the `setA(...)` call ends, this string goes out of scope so it's address is invalid afterwards

So you are trying to free memory from the *heap* in your destructor which was allocated on the *stack* and is long gone at this time...

**Updated suggestion 1:** added on Jan 27th, 2016

- additionally take into account the need of a copy ctor when pushing instances of `A` to a `std::vector`. Obeying the [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) I added a copy assignment operator as well.

  See also [Rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29#Rule_of_Five) in case of [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)
- properly take care of possibly 'wrong' sized strings

  ```
  #include <cstring>

  ...

  /// copy ctor
  A(const A& other) :
          elem(new char[10])
  {
      // prevent duplicate code
      setA(other.elem);
  }

  /// copy assignment operator
  A& operator=(const A& other)
  {
      // prevent duplicate code
      setA(other.elem);

      return *this;
  }

  /// set A's name (which is truncated to 9 characters if necessary)
  void setA(const char* name)
  {
      // copy first 9 chars from name
      // if there's fewer chars: elem is padded with zeros
      std::strncpy(elem, name, 9);

      // add null character / zero (string delimiter) manually
      // this is necessary for cases where name has 10 or more chars
      elem[9] = 0;
  }
  ```

**(Obsolete) suggestion 1:** continue working with c style strings

- explicitly copy the passed string's data (you need to do this in order to make the method work)
- add a length indicator to the parameter list of `setA(...)` (this is optional, you could also figure out the length of the string inside of the method...)

  ```
  #include <cstring>

  ...

  void setA(char* name, size_t length)
  {
      std::memcpy(elem, name, length);
  }
  ```

**Suggestion 2:** switch to c++ style strings

- use `std::string` (I'd prefer this version as it spares you the memory handling and reads very intuitively)

  ```
  #include <string>

  class A
  {
      std::string elem;

  public:
      A(){}

      void setA(std::string name)
      {
          elem = name;
      }

      ~A(){}
  };
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was forcing to use char* so the suggestion 1 worked for me with one change. I have to add the copy constructor because the vector if of object of type A.
    A(const A& other) {
        elem = new char[10];
        std::memcpy(elem, other.elem, 10);
    }

Comment: I added an improved version of suggestion 1. You might consider using it for more robustness when handling strings of different (or wrong) size...

Answer (score 1):

You modify the value of `elem`, which is a pointer to a memory area allocated on the free store. Now, `elem` points to a string literal, which is not applicable to `delete` or `delete[]`.
`delete`ing objects not on the free store is **undefined behavior**. Your destructor attempts it nevertheless.